# How much ethylacetate is produced?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

> 1 mol of acetic acid and 1 mol of ethanol was mixed to react at a constant pressure to reach the equilibrium, and 0.75 mol of water was found in the product.
>
> A. Calculate the equilibrium constant of this reaction at the above temperature
>
> B. At the same temperature, 1 mol acetic acid, 1 mol ethanol, and 4 mol of water were initially mixed to react. Calculate the amount of ethylacetate product after the mixture has reached equilibrium.

A. The equilibrium constant = 9

B. I thought that 4 mol of water reacted with previous product of acetic acid and ethanol so there are 2 mol of acetic acid and 2 mol of ethanol now. I get ethylacetate is 1.5 mol.  The answer is 0.5 mol
How is the reaction actually react?

Comment: 0.5 mol is correct. Now that you have Keq = 9, and water is x+4 and ethyl acetate is x, now solve the quadratic equation. Remember the quadratic has two roots.

Comment: How much acetic acid and ethanol at initial?

Comment: The first line of the question states the initial concentrations. Then determine how much of each is at equilibrium. If you solved part A for Keq, then you should know how to set up an equation to express equilibrium conditions.

Comment: Acetic acid left and ethanol left are 0.25 mol. There are 0.75 mol of ethyl acetate and water each. Then added 1 mol of acetic acid and ethanol each. 4 mol water. So. There are 1.25 mol of acetic acid and ethanol now?

Comment: How can there be more acetic acid and ethanol than you started with?  9 = [x][x+4]/[1-x][1-x]. Solve for x! Only one of the two roots is physically possible. x>0 and x<1.

Comment: I get $8x^2 -14x + 9$

Comment: Watch your signs for the middle term. $8x^2 - 22x + 9 = 0$

Comment: Ok thanks. You don't want to answer in section. So i can give you point

Comment: I didn't want to solve it with an ANSWER. I wanted to direct you in the right direction.